# Uploading Two different xcode files for the Same application as iPhone and Ipad

Tags: ios, app-store

I have created an ipad application. I still haven't uploaded it to the app store, this application has a specific bundle ID.

Meanwhile, I was creating the same application content and features but compatible only with iPhone/Ipod devices.This application has a different bundle ID and a different Xcode file.

So, now i have two Xcode files, one for the iPad and the other one for iPhone, each one with different bundle IDs.

The next step would be uploading this application to the app store, so the situation is , how can i upload it and link two different xcode files together, one for ipad and the other for iPhone

keeping in mind, this is a paid application, so if the user has paid for it on his iPad, he should get the iphone version for free ( on the same App ID ) .

Comment: I don't understand your question, you have an the same app in 2 different Xcode files? One for iPhone and one for iPad? Do they both do the same thing? I am having a hard time understanding why you would have 2 different projects for the same app, why not just disable the features that don't work on the given device?

Comment: The Application is a dictionary, so the first xcode file was an created to be an ipad application, Only iPad application. Meanwhile, i was creating a version of this dictionary to be compatible only with iPhone. But the problem is , i have two xcode files, one for ipad and the other for iPhone, how can i link those two files while uploading the app to the app store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot upload two versions of the same app to the app store.

I suggest consolidating into 1 file, a universal file that will work for BOTH iPhone or iPad.

Other option, would be to create a new app under a different name for iPad or iPhone / iPad only.

Excerpt from Apple's programming guide:

> **Creating a Universal App**
>
> A universal app is a single app that is optimized for iPhone, iPod
>   touch, and iPad devices. Providing a single binary that adapts to the
>   current device offers the best user experience but, of course,
>   involves extra work on your part. Because of the differences in device
>   screen sizes, most of your window, view, and view controller code for
>   iPad is likely to be very different from the code for iPhone and iPod
>   touch. In addition, there are things you must do to ensure your app
>   runs correctly on each device type.
>
> Xcode provides built-in support for configuring universal apps. When
>   you create a new project, you can select whether you want to create a
>   device-specific project or a universal project. After you create your
>   project, you can change the supported set of devices for your app
>   target using the Summary pane. When changing from a single-device
>   project to a universal project, you must fill in the information for
>   the device type for which you are adding support.

Read the full version [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer, and it is logical. One question though, if i upload an application to the App Store, being as Ipad Application, when i upload an updated version later on , with the same bundle ID , can i then change the type to universal ?

Comment: @EliasRahme Migrating 2 apps in the future to make a universal app will not be possible, you would have to submit the new version (whether an update to the iPhone version or the iPad version) and make it a universal app. This of course would leave the other app in the app store behind. It really makes for a sticky situation down the road, I would strongly recommend taking the time to make it universal prior to submission. This way, you won't have to worry about loosing some of your customers that would have downloaded the previous versions and find themselves without support now.

Comment: i want to thank you for your time and for helping me out and i will do it right now. Thank you for your time and effort :)